# Gradle build failure With Disable Offline mode error message

Tags: java, android

When I try to build my project gradle build is failed and show disable offline mode error message. Then disable offline toggle and run it shows 3rd party api 502 Gateway error.

502 GATEWAY ERROR MESSAGE - Could not HEAD 'https://tokbox.bintray.com/maven/com/github/EhsanMashhadi/CountryPicker/0.4.0/CountryPicker-0.4.0.pom'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wWYHB.png)

Comment: Please also post your app level and project level gradle.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.